# select child of child when changing attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working with a CMS to make my websites easy to edit.

To render content on my site i can edit text inline 
 but in the editor i can also select the attribute, like `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p`.

Now the problem is with that attribute selector.

I have a button named(class): `easybutton`

a child div inside `.easybutton`

and inside that child is the text attribute that i try to select in jquery to give it `margin: 0 auto`,

but since my attribute can change i need to select something like this `(.easybutton div).child`

I tried using this code:

```
$(function(){
   var KK = ('.easybutton div');
   var KKC = KK.children;
   $(KKC).css('margin', '0 auto');
});
```

But that does nothing at all.

All answers are welcome.

Ramon

EDIT:

my div direct under .easybutton is only selectable by attribute div, the class values are changing aswell

Comment: Please show the actual HTML. Also, you probably need to use `var KK = $('.easybutton div');`

Comment: @PeterB http://jsfiddle.net/6dqskpLf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired element is the only child then the following one liner will do the trick.

```
$('.easybutton div').children().first().css('margin', '0 auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the KKC variable contains? I think it's an array and you should loop through it

EDIT: this should solve this, a typo missing the function call at KK.children()

```
$(function(){
   var KK = $('.easybutton div');

   var KKC = KK.children();

   $(KKC).css('margin', '0 auto');
});
```

Comment: when i log KKC it has this inside: ƒ (t,e){var n=pt.map(this,o,t);return"Until"!==i.slice(-5)&&(e=t),e&&"string"==typeof e&&(n=pt.filter(e,n)),1<this.length&&(kt[i]||(n=pt.uniqueSort(n)),St.test(i)&&(n=n.reverse())),this.pushStack(n)}

Comment: now i tried doing:   var KK = ('.easybutton');
   var KKC = KK.children;
   console.log(KKC);   and that logs: undefined

Comment: I got KKC undefined in the fiddle you attached anwsering to Peter. 

Can you try this:

$(function(){
   var KK = $('.easybutton div');
   //alert("KK: " + KK)
   var KKC = KK.children();
   //alert("KKC: " +KKC);
   $(KKC).css('margin', '0 auto');
});

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also without jQuery

```
// select div 
var KK = document.querySelector('.easybutton div');
// add style to FIRST child 
KK.children[0].style.margin ="0 auto";
```